# Unable to select (click) anchor link in a floating Div

Tags: html, css, css-float, anchor

I've never seen anything stupid like that, or may be it's 2:30 am and I am hallucinating. I've made simple anchor links within the header and I am completely unable to click on them. They are just plain text and are completely non-clickable.

I'll be thankful if you can give me a hint as what/where I am not obeying the HTML/CSS daemon.

### HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="confine">

        <div class="complete-head-content">

              <div class="left-width-less logo-width">
                  <img src="./imgs/twit-logo.png" />
              </div>

              <div class="right-width-less">
                  <div class="top-header-content">

                         <h1 class="pres-title">Defining Twisted Strategy</h1>
                  </div>

                  <div class="lower-header-content">

                        <div id="navcontainer">
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Meet the Hobos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Why me?</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Work in Oblivion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Perspective</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Approach</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>

                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="c"> </div>
        </div>

    </div>

  </header>

  <div id="contend"> 
  ... ... ...
```

### CSS

```
a {
  color: #EA2E49;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #EA2E49;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.complete-head-content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a0c654;
  height: 130px;
}

.left-width-less {
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 130px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.left-width-less img {

  width : 76px; 
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.right-width-less {
    float: right;
    width: 85%;
}

.top-header-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #437b3c url("../imgs/presentation-title-bg.jpg") no-repeat right;
}

.lower-header-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Navigation */

#navcontainer {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 19px;
}
#navcontainer ul
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

#navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }

#navcontainer ul li a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .2em 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #369;
}
```

### EDIT

Thanks to Nikhil, the  had a Z-index:1 which when removed fixed the bug.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give the full HTML/CSS ? Because this code is working fine on my end : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FfRWC/)

Comment: Ahhh.. I checked your code and I can click all of your anchors. Might be the browser cache or some sort.. or you are working on other source code? ;-) I tried it on firefox and chrome

Comment: You know Nikhil, you just solved it for me. As soon as I selected all code to copy, I inadvertently removed all the other code except listed above. Suddenly this worked. It them dawned on me that the div right next to it was spanning on whole page with z-index:1. I quickly smashed the shit out of it. It obeys now. Many Many Thanks man! :) (Made an edit on my question)

Comment: If you want, you can answer your own question, so that future visitors will see the matter is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you left something out. it is working for me with and without css.
Tested in IE 8

How did you include the CSS btw?

Answer (score 0):

The `<div id="contend">` right next to  tag had a `z-index:1`. This made every link in `<header>` tag non-clickable.

The solution was to remove the z-index property.

Hope it helps someone.